# I want to substitiute medicines on click of substitute button using Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Here is my code. I have uploaded some images so that you can get actual scenario of what I am asking.

And I also want to capture the index of each medicine I am substituting

```
substituteExistMedicine() {
  const subMed = payload

const itemInCart = state.orderedMedicines.filter(item => item.id === subMed.activeId)[0];

const selectedSubstituteItem = state.medicineSubstitution[subMed.index];

const updatedSubstituteList = state.medicineSubstitution.map((substitute, i) => {
  if (i === subMed.index) {
    return {
      ...itemInCart
    };
  }

  return {
    ...substitute
  };
});

const updatedOrderedMedicines = state.orderedMedicines.map(item => {
    if (item.id === subMed.activeId) {
      return {
        ...selectedSubstituteItem
      };
    }

    return {
      ...item
    };
});
console.log('updatedOrderedMedicines', updatedOrderedMedicines)
this.medicineSubstitution = updatedSubstituteList;
},
```

[This is first screen of medicine which has view substitute button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fiqld.png)

[This is Second screen viewing medicine substitute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kisgq.png)

[My actual scenario in which Im not able to substitute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXCp0.png)

Is a nicer solution available?

Note: First screen shows medicines and when click on VIEW SUBSTITUTE then see next screen of substitute results of that medicine.

When I click on SUBSTITUTE, it should replace medicines or I can say swap. which is not happening in my case.

Now this is my updated code I am able to substitute, but it's not reflecting in DOM; what should I do?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show some more code or make a fiddle?

Comment: Hi can you check out my new code and let me know how to update

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand what you want to do. I did a little JS Fiddle example of what I think you're trying to do:

*Script:*

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    medicines: [
        {
            name: 'greatMedicine',
        id: 1, 
        price: '100',
        substitutes: [
        {
          name: 'notSoGreatButCheaper',
          id: 3, 
          price: '20',
        }
        ]
        },
      { 
        name: 'anotherGreatMedicine',
        id: 2, 
        price: '150',
        substitutes: [
        {
          name: 'alsoGreatButCheaper',
          id: 4, 
          price: '30',
        }
        ]
      }
    ],
    showSubsMed: '-1'
  },
  methods: {
    substitute: function(med_index,sub_index){
        let medicine = this.medicines[med_index];
        let substitute = medicine.substitutes[sub_index];

        this.medicines.splice(med_index, 1, substitute);
    }
  }
})
```

*HTML:*

```
<div id="app">
  <h2>Medicines:</h2>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="(med,med_index) in medicines">
       {{med.name}} - {{med.price}}€
       <span v-if="med.substitutes">
       <button @click="showSubsMed === med.id ? showSubsMed = -1 : showSubsMed = med.id" class="btn-primary"> 
         <span v-if="showSubsMed === med.id">hide subs</span>
         <span v-else>show subs</span>
       </button>
        <ol>
        <li v-show="showSubsMed === med.id" v-for="(sub,sub_index) in med.substitutes" class="sub">
           {{sub.name}} - {{sub.price}}€ <button @click="substitute(med_index,sub_index)" class="btn-primary">Substitute!</button>
        </li>
        </ol>
        </span>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5mt0Loka/1/

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I dont have same arrays I have two different arrays

Comment: Hi can you check out my new code and let me know ??

Comment: Appreciate you taking the time, @André.

Comment: Ok, so I don't think using const is the best way to do this. Also, even if the arrays are separated, you can still use this logic :) Good luck!

Comment: Hey @André your code helped me a lot but If I see in jsfiddle, when I click on substitute button, result of substitute is vanished can you persist it even after clicking on Substitute button ??

Comment: Of course, you just need to change your click method to work as you want, Maybe try something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/5mt0Loka/15/